# How to get a more explicit error message when a fetch failed?

Tags: fetch, react-native

I'm on React Native, and
I have a code like this :

```js
fetch('http://someurl.com', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        ...dataSample
    }),
})
.then(response => console.log(response))
.catch(error => console.error(error))
```

The request always go in the catch, with this error result :

```js
{ [[object Error]]
line: 24055,
sourceURL: 'http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false' }
```

NB: When i do a request to the same url/params with postman, the url work very well.

My question is : How can i debug this? and get more explicit error message?

Comment: I think you are not asking for `error.message`, so can you explain?

Comment: What kind of details are you need?

Comment: Is it the server error or js execution error?

Comment: When i do a request to the same url/params with postman, the url work very well. So i think it's not a server error